# Prefill fields with trigger not working

Tags: apex, custom-field, before-trigger, create-records

I have a custom object with 4 required fields for which I made a visualforce page to create a new record. I would like to fill 2 of the required fields with a before trigger and the other 2 trough the visualforce page. One of the required fields to be filled by the trigger is a lookup field.

My trigger fires but I get the error that I need to give a value for the lookup field. Below is my trigger, what am I missing:

```
trigger RelatieContPreFill on Relatie_Contact__c (before insert) {
    User ContactUser =[SELECT Id, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id =:UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
    for (Relatie_Contact__c  Rc : Trigger.new){
        if(trigger.isBefore){
       Rc.Contactpersoon__c=ContactUser.ContactId;//lookup
        Rc.Relatietype__c='Tennis';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be failing when logged in user does not have a ContactId. You might want to default it in such scenario.

Comment: Your query is not necessary. You have `WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()`, and then use the `Id` field of the record returned. You should cut out the middleman and just assign `UserInfo.getUserId()` to your lookup field.

Comment: @derek sorry I updated the query with ContactId

Comment: @Rahul I tested this with a static contact Id but get the same error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of [order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

From that page (emphasis mine):

> On the server, Salesforce:
>
> 1. Loads the original record from the database or initializes the record for an upsert statement.
> 2. Loads the new record field values from the request and overwrites the old values.
>      If the request came from a standard UI edit page, Salesforce runs system validation to check the record for:
>
>    - Compliance with layout-specific rules
>    - **Required values at the layout level and field-definition level**
>    - Valid field formats
>    - Maximum field length
>    - When the request comes from other sources, such as an Apex application or a SOAP API call, Salesforce validates only the foreign keys. Prior to executing a trigger, Salesforce verifies that any custom foreign keys do not refer to the object itself.
>    - Salesforce runs user-defined validation rules if multiline items were created, such as quote line items and opportunity line items.
>
> **3. Executes all before triggers.**

Salesforce is checking for required fields before your `before insert` trigger is being run.

Working around this should be quite simple. I assume you want to prevent users from being able to change `Contactpersoon__c` and `Relatietype__c`.

- You could set values for these two fields at the same time that you set the default values for your other 2 required fields. You would then prevent these from being changed on your visualforce page by using `<apex:outputField>` (as opposed to `<apex:inputField>`)
- Assuming you have a controller extension, you could make a custom `save()` method, and basically just copy/paste your trigger code into it, then call the normal `save()` method

That second approach might look like

```
public class myControllerExtension{
    ApexPages.standardController con;

    public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.standardController controller){
        con = controller;
    }

    public pageReference save(){
        // copy/paste your trigger code here
        // You'll want to be operating on the same object instance that the
        //   standard controller is (i.e. use con.getRecord()).

        // call the controller's save() method to do the rest of the work
        return con.save();
    }
}
```